# How to know which runner is used in VS code?(VS code on WSL)

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a newbie to Visual Studio code and want to make Java development environment where I can debug or run code with the Window Substem Layer while editing project in VS code(, so JDK is only needed on WSL).

Thus, I installed the runner extension and followed [this instruction](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/319).

However, it doesn't work. I couldn't know the exact reason, but I guess it's because the runner is not changed to the new runner(Because the code works well as following, and I set the new runner option as instructed). **I have two runners 'code runner' and 'java test runner', so I want to check which one is used when debugging or running code in VS code.**

[image]

Could you give me any idea about runner check or VS code on WSL? If anything is strange, ask me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that usually in the Java development environment on VS code people guided to install Java Extension Pack, and this extension includes Debugger for Java. Debugger for Java is controlled on debug section as 'launch.json'.

As I use 'code run' menu instead of 'launch.json', I could have used Code Runner extension, not Debugger for Java. Also, I checked Debugger for Java doesn't support WSL bash.